# How to set the value of variables for a label when printing to a zebra printer using the sdk on android

Tags: android, zebra-printers

How can one print a pre-made label (made using Zeba Label Designer) that contains variables and set those variables before printing.

I have the following code, but I am not sure how to set a variable (eg. I have a QR Code in the label I designed and I would like to set its data before printing).

```
TcpPrinterConnection zebraPrinterConnection = new TcpPrinterConnection("192.168.1.100", TcpPrinterConnection.DEFAULT_ZPL_TCP_PORT);
 try {
     ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(zebraPrinterConnection);
     printer.getFileUtil().sendFileContents("/sdcard/documents/labels/sample.lbl");
     zebraPrinterConnection.close();
 } catch (ZebraPrinterConnectionException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ZebraIllegalArgumentException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to look at the output from Zebra Label Designer to get your variables and then hook them up through the sdk

Checkout the documentation that came with the ZebraLink SDK, it has a bunch of good examples on how to print stored formats.  Here's one of the examples. In this example, the "First Name" variable is number 12. The "Last Name" variable is number 11.

```
 ^XA
 ^DFE:FORMAT.ZPL
 ^FS
 ^FT26,243^A0N,56,55^FH\^FN12"First Name"^FS
 ^FT26,296^A0N,56,55^FH\^FN11"Last Name"^FS
 ^FT258,73^A0N,39,38^FH\^FDVisitor^FS
 ^BY2,4^FT403,376^B7N,4,0,2,2,N^FH^FDSerial Number^FS
 ^FO5,17^GB601,379,8^FS
 ^XZ

 TcpPrinterConnection zebraPrinterConnection = new TcpPrinterConnection("192.168.1.32", TcpPrinterConnection.DEFAULT_ZPL_TCP_PORT);
 try {
     zebraPrinterConnection.open();
     ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(zebraPrinterConnection);
     Map<Integer, String> vars = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
     vars.put(12, "John");
     vars.put(11, "Smith");
     printer.getFormatUtil().printStoredFormat("E:FORMAT.ZPL", vars);
     zebraPrinterConnection.close();
 } catch (ZebraPrinterConnectionException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, however when I look at the contents of the lbl file generated by zebra designer it appears to be in binary format. Is there a way to save or convert the .lbl file to a zpl format or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: the label design application lbl file is for the GUI portion of the application, the placement of the fields, etc. You need to export the format as a ZPL file, which looks like the ASCII text from above, sandwiched between the ^XA  ^XZ. To get a ZPL file the printer, click File->Export to printer in ZebraDesigner. (you have to have your printer driver setup correctly) This will save the format on your printer. Conversely, if you don't want it saved on your printer, you can set your driver up to point to a text file, grab the text and send the file every time like you are doing in your example

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but I am stuck with the setting up of my printer drivers correctly. I have searched and searched the web (hence my delayed response) and gone through every screen in the printer properties and printer preferences dialogs but to no avail. Any hints or articles that may help me set things up would be great so that I can move forward. Apologies for the back and forth!

Comment: What model printer do you have? Most likely, you could use the Zebra Setup Utilities - http://www.zebra.com/id/products/global/en/drivers/barcode/zebra_setup_utilities_v1_1_4_838.DriverFile.File.tmp/ZSU_114838.exe?dvar1=Drivers&dvar2=Zebra-Setup-Utilities&dvar3=50            That should help you set up your drivers. If that doesn't help, go to the Printer Properties Ports tab, select "add new port"->Local port. Name it C:\out.txt.  Now every time you "Print" to your driver, it will send it to that file and you can capture that output and send it thru the SDK as you are doing above

Comment: I have installed the tools and do not see anything about changing the configuration as needed. I am using the RW420 Zebra printer model. Per your instructions I have added a local port and printed the file out, however when I open the file i see:     `!  DF 1.FMT
    ! 0 200 200 406 1
    PW 812
    TONE 0
    SPEED 3
    ON-FEED IGNORE
    NO-PACE
    BAR-SENSE
    T 4 0 27 23 I print?
    BOX 6 4 797 392 8
    T 4 0 22 99 \\
    PRINT`

Comment: Ah, you're using a mobile printer. This language is CPCL, so it works a little differently. The '\\' signifies a variable, and there is no number associated with them, it is assumed the first '\\' is var1, the second '\\' is var2, etc. So, you can simply use the code I added in my answer and use 1 as your variable

Comment: For the record I appreciate your perseverance on helping out with this.

Comment: Ok. Eureka. Working well now. Thanks again, hope to return the favor one day!